# NFS share the /home directory inside a local domain with 3 VM's

Tags: debian, virtualbox, nfs

I am at my first year of apprenticeship so I am very new to Linux.

The task I got is:

> Create 3 machines with a Debian based distribution, all three machines
>   should be part of a domain named .elias.de. Each of the machines
>   should have its own name, such as -your-self-selected
>   hostname-.elias.de. Each of the machines should have its own partition
>   for /home, /tmp, /var, /usr. The size of the partitions will be
>   determined at your discretion. Remember that problems may occur later
>   if they are too small. After this has been implemented, each
>   participating machine in the domain should have all 3 users who can
>   log on to the system. The best way to do this is to insert an NFS
>   share in the mountpoint /home. It must be ensured that the NFS share
>   is mounted when the system is started so that users can log on. It is
>   important to check what exactly happens if users are registered in
>   /etc/passwd, but there may be no home directory (in case of network
>   failures, for example) in /home.

OK. So this my stand now:

I have created 3 VM's and configured one as a NFS server and the other 2 as NFS Clients. In Virtual Box i gave them a second network card with Internal Net. So VM1 has 192.168.8.1, VM2 192.168.8.2 and VM3 192.168.8.3 so they can ping each other and thats fine. But now I don't really know how to figure out how to login to i.e. VM1 with the account from VM3. I have never used NFS before so I am stuck at this point. I was already googling for like 3 hours and I get more and more confused.

SO the excat point were I stuck is here:

> After this has been implemented, each participating machine in the
>   domain should have all 3 users who can log on to the system.

I don't want an exact solution, but an approach would be good for me.

If there are any questions regarding my VM's or anything please let me know.

PS: I am using Debian 9 on all the machines and they are up to date.

Comment: So to be clear, you have 3 VM's and you need to have a user be able to log into any 1 of them and have the same home directory/all their files? Your question mentions a Domain, is this an Active Directory/LDAP type setup or is it strictly NFS only?

Comment: It sounds like you have a list of users that need to be on all three machines.  There is the "get it done now" method which would be to just add the exact same user, userid and password to all three machines.  That will achieve what you are trying to do, but is by no means a reliable method of production system deployment as there are many shortcomings to this method.  A more proper method, would be to have a central user database (such as LDAP/Active directory) for all machines to authenticate with.

Comment: @kemotep I should not use LDAP or Active Directory. Just NFS share yes.

Comment: No that was a question for you to determine. If you already have an existing AD/LDAP infrastructure that your users/clients/servers are configured with then the answer to your question will require a setup that supports that. If you do not have that infrastructure then you need to figure out if you will later in the future. I cannot answer whether just NFS setup is better for your environment. What is the scope? Please pay attention to what GracefulRestart is saying. There is the get it done now solution or a more centrally managed solution which can scale over time. Which one do you need?